# Fault in my resource file or resource import for PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, resources

I'm new to working with PyQt for GUI development. As a tutorial for one of the trainings, I'm to develop a phone dialer, which basically just displays a number pad and makes the appropriate dial tones when pressed. This involves importing a resource file that contains the 12 tones. i downloaded the tones from the internet and tested them. They all work just fine. however after I create the resource file, and convert it using pyrcc5, the tones do not play. I've copied the resources.py from the tutorial and the dial pad works as expected. I'm wondering if anyone can help me debug this issue. I haven't seen anything online that shows a similar problem.

if someone can help me attach files, I can add the resource files to the question as well.

Here is a copy of my code although it doesn't appear to be the problem:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
    from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
    from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia as qtmm
    
    import resources1
    
    
    class SoundButton(qtw.QPushButton):
    
        def __init__(self, wav_file, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.wav_file = wav_file
            self.player = qtmm.QSoundEffect()
            self.player.setSource(qtc.QUrl.fromLocalFile(wav_file))
            self.clicked.connect(self.player.play)
    
    
    class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    
        def __init__(self):
            """MainWindow constructor.
    
            This widget will be our main window.
            We'll define all the UI components in here.
            """
            super().__init__()
            # Main UI code goes here
            dialpad = qtw.QWidget()
            self.setCentralWidget(dialpad)
            dialpad.setLayout(qtw.QGridLayout())
    
            for i, symbol in enumerate('123456789*0#'):
                button = SoundButton(f':/dtmf/{symbol}.wav', symbol)
                row = i // 3
                column = i % 3
                dialpad.layout().addWidget(button, row, column)
    
            # End main UI code
            self.show()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
        # it's required to save a reference to MainWindow.
        # if it goes out of scope, it will be destroyed.
        mw = MainWindow()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Don't use fromLocalFile, because that only works for *physical files on your computer*, resources use the qrc "protocol": `SoundButton(f'qrc:/dtmf/{symbol}.wav', symbol)`, then `setSource(qtc.QUrl(wav_file))`.

Comment: Thanks, but the code seems to work fine with the example resource file from the tutorial. Those wave files are not on my computer at all. The resource files that I'm trying to use are on my computer and still doesn't seem to work.  I just tried the command line changes you proposed and it still doesn't work. I believe the issue has to do with the resource files and not necessarily the code. the problem is, I don't know how to attach both files to this question.

Comment: You said that you tested the files, do you mean that if you use their *local path* instead of the qrc, they *do* work? Are you *completely* sure that their path is correct? Note that paths in resources are case sensitive.

Comment: when I tested them, i just opened them up in a player. just to make sure the wave files work. the paths check out. I used QtDesigner to make the qrc, which automatically creates the relative path.

Comment: The fact that they can be reproduced in a player is irrelevant: audio files can use compression even if they are "named" `.wav`, and QSoundEffect can only play uncompressed wave files. Use a basic program to export those files in *actual* **uncompressed** wave files (audacity will do fine).

Comment: I'll try that and let you know...

Comment: uncompressing the wave files worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok. For future reference, try to find al possible means to ensure where the problem actually is: in this case, the problem had nothing to do with resources but with the format, so you could have tried to load the physical file from disk, which wouldn't have worked anyway, but that would have allowed you to rule out the problem with resource loading. In any case, if you use the Qt resource system, I strongly discourage you from using `fromLocalFile`: as said, QRC is similar to a network protocol (like `http://`), so it *must* use an url-like syntax: `QUrl('qrc:/path/to/file')`